# " Cloud Firestore Override a deprecated API " Error occurs when build the flutter application

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

> " Cloud Firestore Override a deprecated API "

Error occurs when building the flutter application.

```
Note: C:\Work\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.11.0+2\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Work\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.11.0+2\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\Work\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\connectivity-0.4.3+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\connectivity\ConnectivityPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Work\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-0.4.0+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FirebaseCorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

minSdkVersion should be 23 at android/app/build.gradle for that cloud_firestore package

Answer (score 1):

In my case, ->android->app->build.gradle
at first I was using library as "compile", changing it to "implementation" my issue got solved